# Який правильний український відповідник англійського "transaction" - трансакція чи транзакція?

Tags: терміни, orthography

На сайті НБУ, розділ "Глосарій банківської термінології", з посиланням на Закон України від 05.04.2001 р. № 2346-III "Про платіжні системи та переказ коштів в Україні" тлумачиться термін "*Тран**с**акція*".

Зокрема, зазначається:

"**ТРАНСАКЦІЯ** (transaction) – термін походить від лат. transactio – дія, договір і ха­рак­теризує: 1) операцію щодо переказу коштів з одного рахунка на інший; 2) ініційовану власником картки послідовність повідомлень, які передають один одному учасники системи для обслуговування власника картки (здійснення доступу до рахунка з метою його дебетування, кредитування чи з’ясування його стану); 3) угоду з цінними паперами; 4) бухгалтерську проводку; 5) угоду, яка супроводжується взаємними поступками. Основними характеристиками Т. є: неподільність, узгодженість, надійність, ізольованість від інших Т. Термін Т. також часто використовують для характеристики будь-якої результативної фінансової чи комерційної операції."

При цьому додається: "У банківській та економічній практиці, зазвичай, використовується напис – «транСакція», а в техніці та інформатиці – «транЗакція»".

Хоча мій досвід свідчить, що навіть спеціалісти фінансового сектору переважно вживають "транЗакція", мало хто вимовляє й пише "транСакція".

Чи врегульоване це питання на рівні термінологічної орфографії?

Answer (score 8):

Маючи відношення до ІТ сфери, особисто я вживаю слово *транзакція*.

В статті [ТЕРМІНОЛОГІЧНА ОРФОГРАФІЯ: ТРАНСАКЦІЯ ЧИ ТРАНЗАКЦІЯ?](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk733/TK_wisnyk733_1_voznjuk_mentynska.htm), що опублікована в Віснику Національного університету «Львівська політехніка» «ПРОБЛЕМИ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ ТЕРМІНОЛОГІЇ» № 733 приводяться такі висновки:

1. Зважаючи на лексичний аспект, лексеми *трансакція* та *транзакція* в різних терміносистемах мають практично однакове значення, тому немає підстав уживати різні орфографічні варіанти.
2. Фонетичний аналіз також не дає підстав для різного написання вищезазначеного терміна, а варіант *транзакція*, цілком очевидно, засвідчує копіювання англійської вимови цього терміна.
3. З погляду деривації відповідним словотвірній моделі й однозначно нормативним слід вважати лише варіант *трансакція*.
4. Не заперечуючи природного процесу інтернаціоналізації в термінології, наголосимо, однак, що надмірна англізація сучасної української термінології на орфоепічному, лексичному чи інших мовних рівнях далеко не завжди сприяє точному називанню певного поняття, а не раз відводить нас від власної мовної традиції.

Answer (score 3):

Транскрипція на [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transaction) каже, що транзакція.

[Lingvo](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Translate/en-uk/transaction) каже, що транзакція.

[Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) каже, що транзакція.

[Англійсько-українські словники](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=transaction&dicts=all&highlight=on) кажуть, що транзакція.

Я не бачу сенсу якось переробляти повністю запозичене слово, літера «з» не має не притаманного українській мові звучання.

P.S. Питання не врегульовано. Обидва варіанти є в орфографічних словниках.

Comment: Дякую. Я теж марно намагалася знайти однозначну відповідь щодо врегулювання питання. Тому й звернулася за допомогою. Ще трапилась стаття (Вознюк Г.  Термінологічна орфографія: трансакція чи транзакція? / Геннадій Вознюк, Ірина Ментинська // Вісник Нац. ун-ту «Львівська політехніка». Серія «Проблеми української термінології» – 2012. – № 733. – С. 6–9.), де автори викладають свою аргументацію за вживання саме терміну "транСакція". Посилання на статтю: [http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk733/TK_wisnyk733_1_voznjuk_mentynska.htm].

Comment: [link] (http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk733/TK_wisnyk733_1_voznjuk_mentynska.htm)

Comment: @Oksana Gubrenko заперечу цим науковцям наступним посиланням: [r2u - транз](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=транз*&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Comment: наскільки я зрозуміла, головний аргумент цих науковців на користь "транСакція" базується на словотворному аспекті (префіксоїд транс-, а не транз-), на відміну від слів "транзит", "транзистор" (за Вашим посиланням), де "транз" - частина кореня.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko Origin and Etymology of transistor: transfer + resistor; from its transferring an electrical signal across a resistor. Я не те щоб кажу, що це саме те, але в англійській мові всі ті решта слів так і читаються, з "с". А транзакція читається з "з". То навіщо тут все упорядковувати, якщо там не упорядковано? Українська ж більше спрямована на милозвучність, не на впорядкування звуків.

Comment: @P.Vovk [Webster’s New World College Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transaction) подає чотири варіанти транскрипції два із /z/, і два з /s/ : /trænˈzækʃən ; tranzakˈshən ; trænˈsækʃən ; transakˈshən/

Comment: @Idolon as for me, there's no reason to go further than the first and the most wide used one.

Answer (score -1):

Переклад "трансакція" був більш поширений до поширення інтернету (в банківській сфері, наприклад), після чого ІТшники по факту просунули свій варіант "транзакція".